Tune Nav2 parameters - Ackermann vehicle
I have an ackermann vechicle and I want to tune the Nav2 params, but I cannot do it well.
This video shows what I have with my current tuning, at first it is ok, but when I'm in the vicinity of the goal the vehicle starts doing "too may" maneuvers.
I don't have lots of expertise with this, can someone help with it?
Here are the nav2 params:
bt_navigator:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    odom_topic: /odom
    default_bt_xml_filename: "navigate_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml"
    bt_loop_duration: 10
    default_server_timeout: 20
    enable_groot_monitoring: True
    groot_zmq_publisher_port: 1666
    groot_zmq_server_port: 1667
    plugin_lib_names:
    - nav2_compute_path_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_compute_path_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_follow_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_back_up_action_bt_node
    - nav2_spin_action_bt_node
    - nav2_wait_action_bt_node
    - nav2_clear_costmap_service_bt_node
    - nav2_is_stuck_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_reached_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updated_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_initial_pose_received_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_reinitialize_global_localization_service_bt_node
    - nav2_rate_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_speed_controller_bt_node
    - nav2_truncate_path_action_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_updater_node_bt_node
    - nav2_recovery_node_bt_node
    - nav2_pipeline_sequence_bt_node
    - nav2_round_robin_node_bt_node
    - nav2_transform_available_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_time_expired_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_distance_traveled_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_single_trigger_bt_node
    - nav2_is_battery_low_condition_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_through_poses_action_bt_node
    - nav2_navigate_to_pose_action_bt_node
    - nav2_remove_passed_goals_action_bt_node
    - nav2_planner_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_controller_selector_bt_node
    - nav2_goal_checker_selector_bt_node

bt_navigator_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

controller_server:
  ros__parameters:
    controller_frequency: 20.0
    min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
    min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.3
    min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.01
    progress_checker_plugins: ["progress_checker"]
    goal_checker_plugins: ["goal_checker"]
    controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]

    progress_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
      required_movement_radius: 0.5
      movement_time_allowance: 10.0
    goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.15
      stateful: True
    FollowPath:
      plugin: "nav2_regulated_pure_pursuit_controller::RegulatedPurePursuitController"
      desired_linear_vel: 0.3
      lookahead_dist: 0.9
      min_lookahead_dist: 0.3
      max_lookahead_dist: 1.5
      lookahead_time: 1.5
      rotate_to_heading_angular_vel: 1.0
      transform_tolerance: 0.1
      use_velocity_scaled_lookahead_dist: false
      min_approach_linear_velocity: 0.05
      approach_velocity_scaling_dist: 1.0
      use_collision_detection: false
      max_allowed_time_to_collision_up_to_carrot: 1.0
      use_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: true
      use_cost_regulated_linear_velocity_scaling: false
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_radius: 0.9
      regulated_linear_scaling_min_speed: 0.25
      use_fixed_curvature_lookahead: true
      curvature_lookahead_dist: 1.0
      use_rotate_to_heading: false

      allow_reversing: true
      
      rotate_to_heading_min_angle: 0.0
      max_angular_accel: 3.2
      max_robot_pose_search_dist: 10.0
      interpolate_curvature_after_goal: false
      cost_scaling_dist: 0.3
      cost_scaling_gain: 1.0
      inflation_cost_scaling_factor: 3.0


controller_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

local_costmap:
  local_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 5.0
      publish_frequency: 2.0
      global_frame: odom
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: False
      rolling_window: true
      width: 10
      height: 10
      resolution: 0.05
      footprint: "[ [0.28, 0.65], [0.28, -0.65], [-1.93, -0.65], [-1.93, 0.65] ]"
      plugins: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        inflation_radius: 0.7
        cost_scaling_factor: 8.0
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
      static_layer:
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  local_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  local_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

global_costmap:
  global_costmap:
    ros__parameters:
      update_frequency: 1.0
      publish_frequency: 1.0
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: base_link
      use_sim_time: True
      footprint: "[ [0.28, 0.65], [0.28, -0.65], [-1.93, -0.65], [-1.93, 0.65] ]"
      resolution: 0.05
      track_unknown_space: true
      plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
      obstacle_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
        enabled: True
        observation_sources: scan
        scan:
          topic: /scan
          max_obstacle_height: 2.0
          clearing: True
          marking: True
          data_type: "LaserScan"
          raytrace_max_range: 3.0
          raytrace_min_range: 0.0
          obstacle_max_range: 2.5
          obstacle_min_range: 0.0
      static_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
        map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      inflation_layer:
        plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
        cost_scaling_factor: 4.0
        inflation_radius: 0.4
      always_send_full_costmap: True
  global_costmap_client:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
  global_costmap_rclcpp_node:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False

map_server:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: True
    yaml_filename: /home/lobna/ros2_ws/map_serial

map_saver:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    save_map_timeout: 5.0
    free_thresh_default: 0.25
    occupied_thresh_default: 0.65
    map_subscribe_transient_local: True

planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    use_sim_time: True

    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerHybrid"
      tolerance: 0.5                                    # tolerance for planning if unable to reach exact pose, in meters
      downsample_costmap: false                         # whether or not to downsample the map
      downsampling_factor: 1                            # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
      allow_unknown: true                               # allow traveling in unknown space
      max_iterations: 1000000                           # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000                  # maximum number of iterations to attempt to reach goal once in tolerance
      max_planning_time: 5.0                            # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth, and upsample. Will scale maximum smoothing and upsampling times based on remaining time after planning.
      motion_model_for_search: "REEDS_SHEPP"            # For Hybrid Dubin (DUBIN), Redds-Shepp (REEDS_SHEPP)
      cost_travel_multiplier: 2.0                       # For 2D: Cost multiplier to apply to search to steer away from high cost areas. Larger values will place in the center of aisles more exactly (if non-`FREE` cost potential field exists) but take slightly longer to compute. To optimize for speed, a value of 1.0 is reasonable. A reasonable tradeoff value is 2.0. A value of 0.0 effective disables steering away from obstacles and acts like a naive binary search A*.
      angle_quantization_bins: 64                       # For Hybrid nodes: Number of angle bins for search, must be 1 for 2D node (no angle search)
      analytic_expansion_ratio: 3.5                     # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The ratio to attempt analytic expansions during search for final approach.
      analytic_expansion_max_length: 3.0                # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The maximum length of the analytic expansion to be considered valid to prevent unsafe shortcutting (in meters). This should be scaled with minimum turning radius and be no less than 4-5x the minimum radius
      minimum_turning_radius: 1.663                     # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: minimum turning radius in m of path / vehicle
      reverse_penalty: 4.1                              # For Reeds-Shepp model: penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
      change_penalty: 1.0                               # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply if motion is changing directions, must be >= 0
      non_straight_penalty: 2.20                        # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
      cost_penalty: 2.0                                 # For Hybrid nodes: penalty to apply to higher cost areas when adding into the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic. This drives the robot more towards the center of passages. A value between 1.3 - 3.5 is reasonable.
      retrospective_penalty: 0.025                      # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: penalty to prefer later maneuvers before earlier along the path. Saves search time since earlier nodes are not expanded until it is necessary. Must be >= 0.0 and <= 1.0
      rotation_penalty: 20.0                            # For Lattice node: Penalty to apply only to pure rotate in place commands when using minimum 
                                                        # control sets containing rotate in place primitives. This should always be set sufficiently high
                                                        # to weight against this action unless strictly necessary for obstacle avoidance or there may be 
                                                        # frequent discontinuities in the plan where it requests the robot to rotate in place to short-cut 
                                                        # an otherwise smooth path for marginal path distance savings.
      lookup_table_size: 20.0                           # For Hybrid nodes: Size of the dubin/reeds-sheep distance window to cache, in meters.
      cache_obstacle_heuristic: True                    # For Hybrid nodes: Cache the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic between subsiquent replannings of the same goal location. Dramatically speeds up replanning performance (40x) if costmap is largely static.  
      allow_reverse_expansion: False                    # For Lattice nodes: Whether to expand state lattice graph in forward primitives or reverse as well, will double the branching factor at each step.   
      smooth_path: True                                 # For Lattice/Hybrid nodes: Whether or not to smooth the path, always true for 2D nodes.
      smoother:
        max_iterations: 1000
        w_smooth: 0.3
        w_data: 0.2
        tolerance: 1.0e-10
        do_refinement: true                             # Whether to recursively run the smoother 3 times on the results from prior runs to refine the results further

planner_server_rclcpp_node:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

recoveries_server:
  ros__parameters:
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    recovery_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/BackUp"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_recoveries/Wait"
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: base_link
    transform_timeout: 0.1
    use_sim_time: true
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

robot_state_publisher:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False

waypoint_follower:
  ros__parameters:
    loop_rate: 200
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

Let me know if you need more information,
Thanks to anyone who helps!

Looks to me like your non-holonomic Ackermann tries to wiggle closer to the goal. There is a parameter
general_goal_checker:
      plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
      xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
      stateful: True

which let's you tune the goal-checker how close the robot should get to a goal w.r.t. its components x y yaw etc.
You can also completely ignore the heading once you reach the goal, which is not a terrible idea for non-holonomic vehicles.
If this does not work, try:

Did you look into nav2 Documentation/Plugins which controllers are generally capable of Ackermann and tried them? You are using Regulated Pure persuit, I have made some better experience with TEB.

To avoid hectic steering, it might be a good idea to tune the underlying low-level controller which has Twist-Msg as input and controls steering and velocity.


Please keep us updated of the solution, Ackermann and NAV2 has me stymied, too!

Hi, thank you for your answer! By "ignoring the heading" you mean increasing the yaw_goal_tolerance? Also, how did you install TEB? (I'm working on Ubuntu 22 with ROS2 Humble)

I mean the code responsible is called goal_checker which checks how close you are to your goal  - hence the name ;). If you tell the goal_checker ignores heading he will prompt goal reached even if your heading is "wrong" w.r.t. to the goal heading.

But I want the vehicle to reach the goal with the right heading

Yes. But it will be very, very hard to achieve that, since you need to plan your trajectory for a "long" time before you reach that goal. Unlike e.g. skid-steered (also non-holonomic btw. but w.r.t. $\dot{y}$) - you can't simply turn in place to reach the correct heading. Hence why I asked you to try a different controller like TEB, with which - and nicely tuned parameters - you might be able to do it.
Also, could you please change the question topic to include "Ackermann"? It's very generic.

I have changed the title :) Do you then know any way to locally (in the proximity of the goal) control the vehicle to reach the exact position? Also, how did you install TEB?

Like I said: for Ackermann there is no way to "control the vehicle to reach the exact position". It is physically impossible - remember what it looks like when you are parking a car in a parking spot parallel to the road: it's wiggling into the spot. Also, while "wiggeling" you will get further away from the goal w.r.t. $x$ and $y$ while trying to get closer to the correct heading. How to use TEB: robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/108108
